# Loess function in ggplot when SE fails

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I would like to plot a loess function with standard errors:

```
geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE)
```

However, I get an error:

```
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
workspace required (XXXXX) is too large probably because of setting 'se = TRUE'.
```

Is there an alternative way, or a fix to get SEs?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data and your complete code using `dput`?

Comment: Subsample your data then repeat it.

Comment: Per the [docs](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_smooth.html), loess “is O(N^2)
 in memory, so does not work for larger datasets.” And therefore by default, “`stats::loess()` is used for less than 1,000 observations; otherwise `mgcv::gam()` is used with `formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")` with `method = "REML"`.” So, you may have to settle for gam instead of loess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to use `mgcv::gam()` instead of `stats::loess()`:

```
geom_smooth(method="gam", se=TRUE)
```